# Desire2Learn Max API Limit

Tags: desire2learn

Is there a max limit on the valance API. I've made a number of calls, but I put some self throttling in the program. It makes a call to the user page, loops through the data, and then makes another call. It probably averaged 1 call every second or so.

I'm looking at expanding some functionality and I'm worried that we may reach a limit if we aren't careful about how we go doing everything.

So, is there a limit to how often we can call the valance api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The back-end LMS can be configured to rate limit on Valence Learning Framework API calls; however, by default this does not get configured as active. To be sure, you should consult with the administrators of your back-end LMS.

Update: Brightspace no longer supports this kind of rate limiting mentioned. As Brightspace evolved, D2L found that the rate limiting was not providing the value that was originally intended, and as a result D2L deprecated the feature. D2L is no longer rate limiting the Brightspace APIs and instead depend on developer self-governance and asynchronous APIs for more resource intensive operations (the APIs around importing courses, for example). When you use the Brightspace APIs, you should be mindful that you are using the same computing resources as made available to end users interacting with the web UI, and if you over-stress these resources (as can easily be done through any API), you can have a negative impact on these end users.

Update again: Brightspace [now does indeed support rate limiting on API calls](https://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/basic/apicall.html#rate-limiting) with a simple token-bucket scheme using headers to communicate your rate-token state, and the `429` status code to signal rate overages.